# wordpress plugin function that will return the character count of the post being saved

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, count, character

I need to have a function that will get the content of the post being saved, count the characters including punctuation and spaces and return a number.

i could use `$text = mb_strlen($text, "UTF-8");`    but i don't know how to call the content of the post i that is currently being saved or updated.

i will be running the function by using `add_action('save_post', 'char_count');` and i don't know how within my function to get the post content of the post being saved so i can run the count script.

Answer (score 0):

`get_post()` gets the post you want by passing in a post ID. That returns an object where the content is in `post_content`, then all you have to do is check the length :

```
$post    = get_post('post_id'); 

$content = $post->post_content;

$length  = strlen($content);
```

If your doing this when saving, it would normally be :

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_save' );

function post_save( $post_id ) {
    $post    = get_post( $post_id ); 
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

    return strlen($content);
}
```